# How to return the first result from XQuery

Tags: xquery

So I have an XQuery that looks something like this:

```
for $i in /*:rootElement
where $i/*:field = "test"
return $i
```

This query returns a lot of results, but I only really need one.  How can I return just the first item in the result sequence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(for $i in /*:rootElement where $i/*:field = "test" return $i)[1]
```

On a side note, a better way to write this is to use step predicates:

```
/*:rootElement[*:field = "test"][1]
```