# Multiple nested levels in a QML XmlListModel

Tags: qml, nested

Given the following XML source with 2 nested levels:

```
<papers>
  <paper id="1">
    <authors>
      <author name="John Doe" />
      <author name="Jane Doe" />
    </authors>
  </paper>
  <paper id="2">
    <authors>
      <author name="John Appleseed" />
    </authors>
  </paper>
</papers>
```

when I define an `XmlRole` in my `XmlListModel` like:

```
XmlListModel {
  id: myPapers
  source: "http://example.com/papers.xml"
  query: "/papers/paper"
  XmlRole { name: "author"; query: "authors/author/@name/string()" }
}
```

it will contain all 3 authors, not only the 2 "Doe" authors from the first paper. I can add an index (`authors/author[1]`) in the role but I **don't now how many papers and authors there will be**. Defining author1, author2, ..., author99 doesn't feel like the right approach.

How do I tell the `XmlListModel` I only want the authors of one paper in a `ListView`?

```
ListView {
  model: myPapers 
  delegate: Text { text: author }
}
```

Now shows:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
John Appleseed <-- don't want this one
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1** The source file is a URL and I prefer *not* to fetch the same file multiple times to get the data (it's for a mobile app).

**UPDATE 2** upsideout on #qt-quick told me it's better to use a `ListView` instead of a `Repeater`. Don't understand why yet. Modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Never tried, but maybe it works if you add an index to the query?
Similar to what is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209382/how-to-return-the-first-result-from-xquery

Comment: Thanks @danielfranca, see my longer response below, it works... but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some more digging and bugged some more people and the final answer is: **no, this is not possible** with a standard `XmlListModel`. You have to roll your own solution.

Here is a snippet of my solution for future references - implementation borrowed from Tim Besard's [BeTrains.QML](https://github.com/iRail/BeTrains.QML/blob/7f2e12a0fb1c6f42accc1616d6aa31e3629680da/qml/BeTrains/pages/ConnectionsPage.qml#L170-L185) code:

```
Item {
    property bool loading: false
    property bool error: false
    property ListModel papers: ListModel{}
    property string source: "http://example.com/papers.xml"

    function fetch() {
        var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
        doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
            error = false;
            if (doc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (doc.status != 200) {
                    error = true;
                } else {
                    var rootNode = doc.responseXML.documentElement;
                    parsePapers(rootNode);
                }
                loading = false;
            }
        }
        loading = true;
        doc.open("GET", source);
        doc.send();
    }

    function parsePapers(rootNode) {
        papers.clear();
        for (var i=0; i < rootNode.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            var node = rootNode.childNodes[i];
            if (node.nodeName == "paper") {
                [snip]...[/snip]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is not only way more complex than the `XmlListModel` solution: It also seems that QML only has basic XML parser capabilities.

Finally, if the "multiple HTTP requests for the same resource" does not matter for you, you can go with the [solution linked by @danielfranca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209391/2538363).

Answer (score 1):

Played with @danielfranca's solution by modifying the query of the `XmlListModel` in the `ListView`:

```
ListView {
  model: XmlListModel {
    query: "/paper/authors["+(index+1)+"]"
  }
  Text { text: author }
}
```

This works, but... in my use case the XML source is a URL meaning this will create another HTTP request for each list. This is unnecessary as the data is already there with the first request. Anyone a better solution?